# How to tell if there is any extra input?

Tags: c++

In my case I am trying to read exactly 3 strings (or any fixed number). `string1` `string2` `string3`
using `cin >> string1 >> string2 >> string3`.
How do I tell if there was something else, except for whitespaces, in the input stream, such as extra characters, etc.?

Comment: You could read a fourth string and see whether it is empty and `cin.eof()` has been set.

Comment: The same/similar way you acquired the strings you did: try and read them. I assume you verified the read you showed actually succeeded first, *right* ?

Comment: Just like with a file, we would typically read until the error flag is set on the stream. If you're running the program during an interactive session (vs piping the stdout from one program into the stdin for your program), then you will probably want to take a different approach such as requiring the user to enter a special "sentinel" input indicating they are finished.